# Pandas DataFrame Time index using .loc function error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing

I have created DataFrame with DateTime index, then I split the index into the Date index column and Time index column. Now, when I call for a row of a specific time by using pd.loc(), the system shows an error.

Here're an example of steps of how I made the DataFrame from beginning till reaching my consideration.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'B':[5, 6, 7, 8], 'C':[9, 10, 11, 12],
    'DateTime':pd.to_datetime(['2021-09-01 10:00:00', '2021-09-01 11:00:00', '2021-09-01 12:00:00', '2021-09-01 13:00:00'])})

df=df.set_index(df['DateTime'])
df.drop('DateTime', axis=1, inplace=True)
df
```

**OUT >>**

```
                    A   B   C
DateTime            
2021-09-01 10:00:00 1   5   9
2021-09-01 11:00:00 2   6   10
2021-09-01 12:00:00 3   7   11
2021-09-01 13:00:00 4   8   12
```

**In this step, I'm gonna splitting DateTime index into multi-index Date & Time**

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.date, df.index.time], names=['Date','Time'])
df
```

**OUT >>**

```
                        A   B   C
     Date   Time            
2021-09-01  10:00:00    1   5   9
            11:00:00    2   6   10
            12:00:00    3   7   11
            13:00:00    4   8   12
```

***##Here is the issue##***

when I call this statement, The system shows an error

```
df.loc["11:00:00"]
```

How to fix that?

Comment: So do you want to select every `11:00:00` from every Date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. If you want to use `.loc`, you can just specify the time by:

```
import datetime

df.loc[(slice(None), datetime.time(11, 0)), :]
```

or use [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html) similar to the solution by BENY, as follows:

```
import datetime

idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:,datetime.time(11, 0)], :]
```

(defining a variable `idx` to use [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html) gives us cleaner code and less typing if you are going to use [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html) multiple times).

**Result:**

```
                     A  B   C
Date       Time              
2021-09-01 11:00:00  2  6  10
```

#### 2. If you want to select just for one day, you can use:

```
import datetime

df.loc[(datetime.date(2021, 9, 1), datetime.time(11, 0))]
```

**Result:**

```
A     2
B     6
C    10
Name: (2021-09-01, 11:00:00), dtype: int64
```

#### 3. You can also use [`.xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) to access the MultiIndex row index, as follows:

```
import datetime

df.xs(datetime.time(11,0), axis=0, level='Time')
```

**Result:**

```
            A  B   C
Date                
2021-09-01  2  6  10
```

#### 4. Alterative way if you haven't split DateTime index into multi-index Date & Time

Actually, if you haven't split the DatetimeIndex into separate date and time index, you can also use the [`.between_time()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) function to filter the time, as follows:

```
df.between_time("11:00:00", "11:00:00")
```

You can specify a range of time to filter, instead of just a point of time, if you specify different values for the *start_time* and *end_time*.

**Result:**

```
                     A  B   C
DateTime                     
2021-09-01 11:00:00  2  6  10
```

As you can see, [`.between_time()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) allows you to enter the time in simple string to filter, instead of requiring the use of datetime objects.  This should be nearest to your tried ideal (but invalid) syntax of using `df.loc["11:00:00"]` to filter.

As a suggestion, if you split the DatetimeIndex into separate date and time index simply for the sake of filtering by time, you can consider using the [`.between_time()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) function instead.

Comment: @Mahome  Welcome!  As a suggestion, if you split the  DatetimeIndex into separate date and time index simply for the sake of filtering by time, you can also consider using the `.between_time()` function I mentioned above.

Comment: it's kind of you that you have covered multiple ways. I really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1):

We can just do the correct value slice with `IndexSlice`

```
import datetime
out = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,datetime.time(11, 0)],:]
Out[76]: 
                     A  B   C            DateTime
Date       Time                                  
2021-09-01 11:00:00  2  6  10 2021-09-01 11:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to split your datetime into two parts?

You can use [`indexer_at_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_at_time.html)

```
>>> df
                     A  B   C
DateTime
2021-09-01 10:00:00  1  5   9
2021-09-01 11:00:00  2  6  10
2021-09-01 12:00:00  3  7  11
2021-09-01 13:00:00  4  8  12

# Extract 11:00:00 from any day
>>> df.iloc[df.index.indexer_at_time('11:00:00')]
                     A  B   C
DateTime
2021-09-01 11:00:00  2  6  10
```

You can also create a proxy to save time typing:

```
T = df.index.indexer_at_time
df.iloc[T('11:00:00')]
```